# Need help modeling data with a log() function

Tags: r, prediction

I have some data that Excel will fit pretty nicely with a logarithmic trend.  I want to pass the same data into R and have it tell me the coefficients and intercept.  What form should have the data in and what function should I call to have it figure out the coefficients? Ultimately, I want to do this thousands of time so that I can project into the future.

Passing Excel these values produces this trendline function: `y = -0.099ln(x) + 0.7521`

Data:

```
y <- c(0.7521, 0.683478429, 0.643337383, 0.614856858, 0.592765647, 0.574715813, 
       0.559454895, 0.546235287, 0.534574767, 0.524144076, 0.514708368)
```

For context, the data points represent % of our user base that are retained on a given day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question omitted the value of `x` but working backwards it seems you were using 1, 2, 3, ... so try the following:

```
x <- 1:11
y <- c(0.7521, 0.683478429, 0.643337383, 0.614856858, 0.592765647, 
     0.574715813, 0.559454895, 0.546235287, 0.534574767, 0.524144076, 
     0.514708368)
fm <- lm(y ~ log(x))
```

giving:

```
> coef(fm)
(Intercept)      log(x) 
     0.7521     -0.0990
```

and

```
plot(y ~ x, log = "x")
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results by:

```
y <- c(0.7521, 0.683478429, 0.643337383, 0.614856858, 0.592765647, 0.574715813, 0.559454895, 0.546235287, 0.534574767, 0.524144076, 0.514708368)
t <- seq(along=y)
> summary(lm(y~log(t)))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ log(t))

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-3.894e-10 -2.288e-10 -2.891e-11  1.620e-10  4.609e-10 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.521e-01  2.198e-10 3421942411   <2e-16 ***
log(t)      -9.900e-02  1.261e-10 -784892428   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.972e-10 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 6.161e+17 on 1 and 9 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

For large projects I recommend to encapsulate the data into a data frame, like

```
df <- data.frame(y, t)
lm(formula = y ~ log(t), data=df)
```

Comment: Excellent response.  Thank you.  I actually need to do this for hundreds of cohorts each day.  Each cohort will have a varied number of data points available (based on how long they have been active).  How would you approach bringing in a whole bunch of cohorts with varied amounts of history and modeling each to get the coef()?

Comment: I would do a simple loop with `lm()` inside.  It very much depends on how do you fetch the data for each cohort, and what will you do with the results.